# Reference request : Hoffman type bound for non-regular graph based on min and max degree

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for a reference for the following bound. it's relatively trivial, but I've never seen it anywhere.

Let $G$ be a graph with min degree $\delta$ and max degree at most $\Delta$. I claim that the independence number of $G$ (the largest cardinality of any set of independent vertices) satisfies
$$ \alpha(G)\leq n\left(1-\frac{\delta}{\delta+\Delta}\right) .$$

**Proof Idea:** I'm using Hofman's bound for non-regular graphs, based on $\lambda_\max$, the largest Laplacian eigenvalue for $G$ :
$$ \alpha(G)\leq n\left(1-\frac{\delta}{\lambda_\max}\right) .$$
see [Haemers, *Interlacing eigenvalues and graphs*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595001992) for reference. Then using  [Anderson, Morley, *Eigenvalues of the Laplacian of a graph*](https://doi.org/10.1080/03081088508817681),  for any graph $G$,
$$ \lambda_\max \leq \max_{ij \in E(G)} d_i+d_j.$$

Then let $G$ be a graph maximizing $\alpha(G)$ over all graphs with min degree $\delta$ and max degree at most $\Delta$. Assume that there exist an edge $e$ for which both end-vertices have degree strictly larger than $\delta$. Then $G'=G-e$ is still a graph with min degree $\delta$ and max degree at most $\Delta$, and as we only deleted an edge we have $\alpha(G)\leq \alpha(G')$. As $\alpha(G)$ was a maximum, then $\alpha(G)=\alpha(G')$. Therefore without loss of generality I can assume that any edge of $G$ is incident to at least one vertex of min degree. i.e.
$$ \lambda_\max \leq \max_{ij \in E(G)} d_i+d_j \leq \delta+\Delta,$$
and we get
$$ \alpha(G)\leq n\left(1-\frac{\delta}{\delta+\Delta}\right).$$

As $G$ is maximzing this value, this inequality holds for any graph with min degree $\delta$ and max degree at most $\Delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a proof that does not require eigenvalues.

Let $S$ be an independent set of size $\alpha$. Then there are at least $\delta \cdot \alpha$ edges from $S$ to $V-S$. On the other hand, there are at most $\Delta \cdot (n-\alpha)$ such edges, since each vertex in $V-S$ gets at most $\Delta$ of them. Therefore $$\delta \cdot \alpha \le \Delta \cdot (n-\alpha) \implies \alpha \le n \cdot \frac{\Delta}{\delta + \Delta} = n\left(1 - \frac{\delta}{\delta+\Delta}\right).$$
For the $\delta=2$ case, this is Lemma 1 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mingyu-Xiao/publication/221427022_A_Note_on_Vertex_Cover_in_Graphs_with_Maximum_Degree_3/links/60618b1e458515e8347c2779/A-Note-on-Vertex-Cover-in-Graphs-with-Maximum-Degree-3.pdf), and it can probably be found elsewhere, too.